# What to write in "outline of research program"

Tags: funding, application-cover-letter, supporting-information

I am applying for a scholarship to support my final stages of PhD. One document required by the scholarship grant committee requires me to provide "Outline of the research program".

What should I write in this document? Note that I am almost done with my research and now I am almost finishing my thesis as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the purpose for which the scholarship is designed and also on who typically applies for it.

In either case you should describe both where your research has gone up to now and where it will go as you complete it, but the emphasis might be different depending on the intent of the scholarship. You should also say something about what you expect to explore after you finish the degree - problems yet to solve.

If the scholarship is intended for final stage support then the emphasis should be on the final stages and less (but something) on what got you to this point.

But if it is a general scholarship and is open to beginners as well as people like yourself, then describe the whole program from start to end, saying where you currently are in that process. In other words, more emphasis on the earlier stages than in the other scenario, but indicating that much of it is done.

Don't give the impression, however, that you are so close to the end that support isn't needed. Your entire degree is just a part of a "research program" that you can continue after finishing the degree.